# How to dock datagridview to parent container but leave space for search fields?

Tags: c#, datagridview

- I want to leave some space for search fields on the top of
  datagridview but also want to dock my datagridview to parent
  container, so when I open the application as maximize it should fit
  the screen.

below are the images to explain you better.

- If I dock the datagridview to parent container

[image]

- if I undock datagridview and add search fields on the top of it (Without running application).

[image]

- if I open the datagridview form in maximize form it looks like this.
  I want to leave some space for search fields but dock the remaining
  datagridview to maximize window. (When I run the app).

[image]

Comment: Use  the Anchor properties instead of Dock!

Comment: If the panel on top is Dock.Top, then just right click on the grid and choose "Send To Back" or "Bring To Front".

Comment: Stretch the datagridview(DGV) from right and bottom, and then as @TaW suggested apply the Anchor properties of Top, bottom, right and left on the DGV.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use two panels, one is Dock top and another Dock fill, place your grid in the second panel and make it also dock fill.  You can apply dome padding for the grid by setting padding property in the second panel.

[image]

Comment: I don't know why people are so quick to vote-down, if I knew the answer I wouldn't be coming here and asking on stackoverflow, ofcourse when we get stucked somewhere we have to put up our question.

Thanks Damith.

Comment: @Patrick, you are welcome!, this is one way to do this using panels but you better lean the techniques of windows layout controls. read more and do some samples to improve your self. you can find many resources. one other way is using table layout control, check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492143.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I learn up things as they come up to me either I find myself or if I get stucked and have no clue, I have to put up question. thanks.

Comment: _I don't know why people are so quick to vote-down_ Well your question doesn't exactly show __any__ research effort. But this is __required__ for SO question! Do take a trip to the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) !

Comment: You could have asked for it. anyways i'll take some popcorn with me to help center.